# Почему этот код не выводит значение атрибута на страницу?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Значение созданного атрибута data-a должно выводиться в элемент с классом out. Этого не происходит. Почему?

```js
let el = document.querySelector('.one');
el.setAttribute('data-a', '168');

document.querySelector('.out').innerHtml = el.getAttribute('data-a');
```

```html
<div class="one">TEXT</div>
<div class="out">out</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Найдите 3 отличия))

```js
let el = document.querySelector('.one');
el.setAttribute('data-a', '168');

document.querySelector('.out').innerHTML = el.getAttribute('data-a');
```

```html
<div class="one">TEXT</div>
<div class="out">out</div>
```

А чтобы не делать таких ошибок - используйте *IDE* с автодополнением

Comment: А еще такой вопрос. Раньше думал, что можно употреблять только определенные атрибуты, например `value`, `alt`... Но как я вижу, можно придумывать свои атрибуты. Вопрос: созданные мной атрибуты могут иметь любое название? здесь нет каких-то специальных правил?

Comment: @Ivan не припомню правил. Одно могу сказать, что для кастомных значений стоит использовать правило `data-НАЗВАННИЕ`, например `data-user-id` или `data-element-type` или `data-unit` и  т.д. тогда с ними можно работать через dataset (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset  ... На русском: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes). Например в  element.dataset будет храниться объект `{userId: 5, elementType: 'point', unit: 546}`. Очень удобно и это бОлее распространённое среди разработчиков. Почитайте ссылку